# Python - Como imprimo contenido de diccionario de forma ordenada

Tags: python, python-3.x, diccionarios

Para un diccionario `dicc_n` que contiene los nombres de n estudiantes como claves y una lista con las notas de tipo float como valores, además de eso, luego imprimir el promedio de esas notas, me gustaría que al imprimir el diccionario aparezca de la siguiente forma:

Notas: 'nombre' -> notas -> promedio

y no:

`{'nombre':[[notas],[promedio]]}`

Ejemplo:
`{'Juan':[[5,4,5,3],[4.25]],'Marcos':[[4.0,5.0],[4.5]]}`

Resultado esperado luego de imprimir:

Notas:

Juan -> 5 , 4 , 5, 3 -> Promedio = 4.25

Marcos -> 4.0 , 5.0 -> Promedio = 4.5

Comment: podrias poner un ejemplo del diccionario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Teniendo un diccionario así:

```py
dic = {'Juan':[[5,4,5,3],[4.25]],'Marcos':[[4.0,5.0],[4.5]]}
```

Lo unico que tenemos que hacer es recorrerlo para acceder a cada uno de sus elementos, esto se hace con un ciclo for

```py
for name in dic.keys():
    #convertimos cada elemento a string
    notas = [str(n) for n in dic[name][0]] 
    prom = [str(n) for n in dic[name][1]]
    #imprimimos
    print(f"{name} ->  {','.join(notas)} Promedio = {','.join(prom)}")
```

al imprimir hacemos uso de una compresión de lista y el método `.join()`, la compresión de lista es lo mismo que un ciclo `for`, en ese caso recorremos la lista y convertimos cada elemento a un string, para que al momento de usar `.join()` no tengamos problemas. El método `",".join()` lo que hace es unir los elemento de la lista según el carácter que le pasemos en este caso `,`, teniendo como resultado.

```py
Juan ->  5,4,5,3 Promedio = 4.25
Marcos ->  4.0,5.0 Promedio = 4.5
```